# What's wrong with appendingPathComponent, is it optional?

Tags: ios, xcode, url, switch-statement, option-type

I can't close my code because an issue, is it optional yet?
In the 'if let rutaMemoria' line it appears: "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'URL'"

```
    for archivo in archivos {

        let nombreArchivo = archivo.lastPathComponent

            if nombreArchivo.hasSuffix(".thumb") {
                let sinExtension = nombreArchivo.replacingOccurrences(of: ".thumb", with: "")

                if let rutaMemoria = obtenerDirectorioDocs().appendingPathComponent(sinExtension){
                recuerdos.append(rutaMemoria)
                }
            }
        }
```

and when I remove the 'if', xcode shows me this error in the line below (in recuerdos.append): "Variable used within its own initial value"

```
for archivo in archivos {

    let nombreArchivo = archivo.lastPathComponent

        if nombreArchivo.hasSuffix(".thumb") {
            let sinExtension = nombreArchivo.replacingOccurrences(of: ".thumb", with: "")

            let rutaMemoria = obtenerDirectorioDocs().appendingPathComponent(sinExtension){
            recuerdos.append(rutaMemoria)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: oh I forgot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, `appendingPathComponent` is non-optional, `it let` is only for optionals

Replace

```
let rutaMemoria = obtenerDirectorioDocs().appendingPathComponent(sinExtension){
    recuerdos.append(rutaMemoria)
}
```

with

```
let rutaMemoria = obtenerDirectorioDocs().appendingPathComponent(sinExtension)
recuerdos.append(rutaMemoria)
```